# How to hash by choosing the key and the string value with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm traying to hash urls with Ruby but I had some problems the size of my urls differs from one url to another, hence my hash key doesn't give me the right result.

2 examples of my urls

```
url1="Services/tech_name/prise/name_Prise/service_name/sites/xxxx/yyyy/devices/AAAA/wan/16170515?startDate=2021-01-18T23:00: 00.000Z&endDate=2021-01-19T08:22:42.000Z& timeProfile=1&tz=CET"

url2="Services/tech_name/prise/name_Prise/service_name/sites/xxxx/yyyy/devices/AAAA/BBBB/wan/1617051?startDate=2021-01-18T23:00: 00.000Z&endDate=2021-01-19T08:22:42.000Z& timeProfile=1&tz=CET"
```

Example of my code to hash url1:

```
url1="Services/tech_name/prise/name_Prise/service_name/sites/xxxx/yyyy/devices/AAAA/wan/16170515?startDate=2021-01-18T23:00: 00.000Z&endDate=2021-01-19T08:22:42.000Z& timeProfile=1&tz=CET"

spliturl=my_url.gsub("?","/")
url=spliturl.split("/")
if !url.count.even?
  url.push(nil)
  h=Hash[*url]
  puts h 
end
```

My result:

```
{"Services"=>"name_services", "prise"=>"name_prise", "tech"=>"sites", "xxxx"=>"yyyy", "devices"=>"AAAA", "wan"=>"16170515", "startDate=2021-01-18T23:00:00.000Z&endDate=2021-01-19T08:22:42.000Z&timeProfile=1&tz=CET"=>nil}
```

The "sites" has become a **value** and the "sites" value has become a **key** !!

```
{"tech"=>"sites", "xxxx"=>"yyyy", "devices"=>"AAAA", "wan"=>"16170515"}
```

But the result I would like to have from url1:

```
{"sites" => "xxxx/yyyy", "devices" => "AAAA", "wan" => "16170515"}
```

and from url2:

```
{"sites" => "xxxx/yyyy", "devices" => "AAAA/BBBB", "wan" => "1617051"}
```

Comment: While you might be able to do what you want, your web application is poorly suited for it. Unless you know ahead of time what parts of your path are values and which are keys, breaking apart a non-REST URI with queries is going to yield inconsistent results in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

I have one idea how you could solve the problem:

```
result = url1.match /\/sites\/(?<sites>.*)\/devices\/(?<devices>.*)\/wan\/(?<wan>.*)\?/
```

Then to get values from results:

```
result[:sites] => "xxxx/yyyy"
result[:devices] => "AAAA"
result[:wan] => "16170515"
```

Comment: think you @ag4ta